# "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I'm working on Oracle Apex 5, and when I try to run the application with the following code for a column I get an error saying "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"

```
DECLARE
  Num VARCHAR2(40);
BEGIN
  SELECT CONCAT(YEAR, '-')
 INTO Num FROM APPS;
END;
```

Comment: Just try running `SELECT CONCAT(YEAR, '-') FROM MP_APPLICATIONS`. You'll see that it returns more than one row which obviously cant be put in a single variable. Do you want to get any one of the values? max/min perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable terranumber can hold only one value. So, if you select query returns multiple rows, it is going to throw this error.

If you want any one of the values:

```
declare
    terranumber varchar2(40);
begin
    select concat(year, '-') into terranumber 
    from mp_applications
    where rownum = 1;
end;
/
```

Perhaps you want to get `max` (or `min`) of year:

```
declare
    terranumber varchar2(40);
begin
    select concat(max(year), '-') into terranumber 
    from mp_applications;
end;
/
```

Or may be you want to access all the values one by one:

```
begin
    for rec in (select concat(year, '-') as year from mp_applications)
    loop
        -- use rec.year as required
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: When I use the rownum it just gets the first row from the columns that are called (in concat). How can I get the most recent rows for the columns? (TOP and LIMIT are not working on Oracle Apex 5)

Comment: @thelamp you can play with **rownum** value: **select * from (your select + order by date)where ROWNUM < 10**

Answer (score 0):

Only one row may be SELECTed when using an INTO clause.  Generally you add WHERE clause criteria to restrict the data returned to be just one row.  Or course that depends on what you are trying to do.